# Post a map to Firestore Collection Set with flutter | Expressions can't be used in a map literal

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a  Usermodel where it take phoneNumber, username, Password, etc and i want to convert it to a json data for firestore collection set.
But when i try to put userModel.toJson() in firestore collection set it get the Error Message Bellow.

**Auth.dart**

```
UserModel userModel = UserModel(
    phoneNumber: "12345678",
    userName: "Caivy",
    bio: 'Edit profile to update bio',
    displayName: "Caivy",
    location: 'Somewhere in universe',
    isVerified: false,
  );
await _firestore.collection('users').doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).set(
                              {
                                userModel
                                    .toJson(), ==> Error Message from here.
                              },
```

**UserModel.dart and Usermodel.g.dart**

```
class UserModel {
  String? phoneNumber;
  String? userId;
  String? displayName;
  String? userName;
  String? profilePic;
  String? contact;
  String? bio;
  String? location;
  String? dob;
  String? createdAt;
  bool? isVerified;
  int? followers;
  int? following;
  String? fcmToken;
  List<String>? followersList;
  List<String>? followingList;

  UserModel({
    this.phoneNumber,
    this.userId,
    this.displayName,
    this.profilePic,
    this.contact,
    this.bio,
    this.dob,
    this.location,
    this.createdAt,
    this.userName,
    this.followers,
    this.following,
    this.isVerified,
    this.fcmToken,
    this.followersList,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromJson(
          Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$UserModelFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      _$UserModelToJson(this);
}

UserModel _$UserModelFromJson(
        Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    UserModel(
      phoneNumber: json['phoneNumber'] as String?,
      userId: json['userId'] as String?,
      displayName: json['displayName'] as String?,
      profilePic: json['profilePic'] as String?,
      contact: json['contact'] as String?,
      bio: json['bio'] as String?,
      dob: json['dob'] as String?,
      location: json['location'] as String?,
      createdAt: json['createdAt'] as String?,
      userName: json['userName'] as String?,
      followers: json['followers'] as int?,
      following: json['following'] as int?,
      isVerified: json['isVerified'] as bool?,
      fcmToken: json['fcmToken'] as String?,
      followersList:
          (json['followersList'] as List<dynamic>?)
              ?.map((e) => e as String)
              .toList(),
    )..followingList =
        (json['followingList'] as List<dynamic>?)
            ?.map((e) => e as String)
            .toList();

Map<String, dynamic> _$UserModelToJson(
        UserModel instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'phoneNumber': instance.phoneNumber,
      'userId': instance.userId,
      'displayName': instance.displayName,
      'userName': instance.userName,
      'profilePic': instance.profilePic,
      'contact': instance.contact,
      'bio': instance.bio,
      'location': instance.location,
      'dob': instance.dob,
      'createdAt': instance.createdAt,
      'isVerified': instance.isVerified,
      'followers': instance.followers,
      'following': instance.following,
      'fcmToken': instance.fcmToken,
      'followersList': instance.followersList,
      'followingList': instance.followingList,
    };
```

**Dependency : Flutter Version is Stable Latest (2.5.3)**

```
dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: "^1.7.0"
  firebase_auth: "^3.1.3"
  cloud_firestore: "^2.5.3"
  flutter_facebook_auth: "^3.5.0"
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  provider: ^6.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.10
  json_serializable: ^6.0.1
  build_runner: ^2.1.5
  json_annotation: ^4.3.0
```

> Expressions can't be used in a map literal.
> Try removing the expression or converting it to be a map entry.dart(expression_in_map)

Comment: Is it possible you meant to do this instead? `await _firestore.collection('users').doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).set(userModel.toJson())`

Comment: Omg, Yes that it Thanks you so much

Comment: As you have placed curly braces after set...and you are already passing a map as well, so removing the curly braces after set will solve the problem.